# How to access a PHP variable from one function in another function

Tags: php, scope, laravel-5

I have already written an application in a procedural way and am trying to move into into a Laravel framework.  I'm having trouble with the SOAP exchange section as I am getting an ID value that authenticates the user but cannot access that value (as a cookie) later in the program to authenticate the search.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class SoapController {

private $auth_response;
private $cookie;
private $search_client;
private $search_response;

public function soapExchange() {

    // create SOAP client and add service details
    SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {

        $service
            ->name('WoSAuthenticate')
            ->wsdl('http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl')
            ->trace(true)
            ->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE);
    });

    SoapWrapper::service('WoSAuthenticate', function($service) {
        // call authenticate() method to get SID cookie
        $auth_response = $service->call('authenticate', []);
        $cookie = $auth_response->return;
        // test for cookie return
        // print($cookie);
    });

    // create SOAP client and add service details
    $search_client = new SoapWrapper;
    $search_client::add(function ($service) {

        $service
            ->name('WoSSearch')
            ->wsdl('http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl')
            ->trace(true)
            ->cache(WSDL_CACHE_NONE);
    });

    if (isset($auth_response->return)) {

        // if there is an SID returned then add it to the cookie attribute of the search client
        $search_client->__setCookie('SID', $cookie);
    } else {
        // route to relevant view to display throttle error
        return redirect('throttle');
    }
}
}
```

I am successfully retrieving the response from the Web API call and getting a code to authenticate the user, saved as `$cookie`.  However, I need then to create another `SoapWrapper` for performing the search and this needs the ID code attached by using the `__setCookie` method.  If nothing is returned by the `authenticate` call then it redirects to an error message via `throttle.blade.php` elsewhere.

Surely there is a way to return a value created from a function so that it can be used elsewhere?

** EDIT **

Looked into employing `SoapClient` instead and including all operations within a single function.  It all relates to a specific Web API anyway so I guess separation of concerns is not so much of an issue.  FYI the new class I am trying is this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class SoapWrapper {

public function soapExchange() {

    // set WSDL for authentication and create new SOAP client
    $auth_url  = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";

    // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
    $auth_client = @new SoapClient($auth_url);

    // set WSDL for search and create new SOAP client
    $search_url = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WokSearch?wsdl";

    // array options are temporary and used to track request & response data
    $search_client = @new SoapClient($search_url);

    // run 'authenticate' method and store as variable
    $auth_response = $auth_client->authenticate();

    // call 'setCookie' method on '$search_client' storing SID (Session ID) as the response (value) given from the 'authenticate' method
    // check if an SID has been set, if not it means Throttle server has stopped the query, therefore display error message
    if (isset($auth_response->return)) {
        $search_client->__setCookie('SID',$auth_response->return);
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('throttle');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what about the "use" operator in anonymous functions - is this something you can work with? 
Usage: $two = function() use ($result) { var_dump($result); };

Comment: I did look into that but it seems that you can only use that method if the function where you put the `use` operator is nested within the function containing the variable.  Not sure if that will work but I'll give it a try...

Comment: you can use global variable see manual http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;    


class SoapController extends Controller {

    public $resultSoapStatus;
    public $resultSoapAuthority;

    public function heySoap{

        SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) ...

        $data = [
                'MerchantID'       => $MerchantID,
                'Amount'           => $Amount,
                'Description'      => $Description,
                'Email'            => $Email,
                'Mobile'           => $Mobile,
                'CallbackURL'      => $CallbackURL
            ];

        SoapWrapper::service('test', function ($service) use ($data) {
          $resultSoap = $service->call('PaymentRequest', [$data]);
          $this->resultSoapStatus    = $resultSoap->Status;
          $this->resultSoapAuthority = $resultSoap->Authority;
             });

         if($this->resultSoapStatus == 100 && strlen($this->resultSoapAuthority) == 36)
          {
           //Do Something
          }
          else
          {
            return Redirect::back();
          }


      }
}
```

Enjoy bro

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try $GLOBALS?

```
<?php
$GLOBALS[data] = "something";

function abc(){
   echo $GLOBALS[data];
}
?>
```

Comment: I thought it was a bit of a security risk to use global variables?